# How to change the OrderStatus of one Order from an Address Interceptor? Hybris Commerce

Tags: java, spring, interceptor, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working in a Hybris Commerce custom project and this is my case:

1 - I have an `Interceptor` for `AddressModel`, it's run when I do insert or Update.

2 - I have to change the `Order.Status` value when I update a value in Address.

If someone knows how to get de OrderModel from Address to set a value it will be nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was..

```
 OrderModel orderModel = (OrderModel) addressModel.getOwner();
```

Casting you can get de full object and to change the status. I save it after set my value, using model service:

```
orderModel.setValue(true);
modelService.save(orderModel);
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: of-course you need to cast it because `Owner` attribute at its definition can accept any `ItemModel`. Don't see any different from the answer given above. Anyways... Good Luck!

Comment: If none of the answers worked for you and you got a different solution then you can always answer your question and mark it accepted. But in this case, @hybriscx has already answered it.

Answer (score 1):

In your address interceptor, take the hold of the `OrderModel` and use model service to save your order model object.

Something like `modelService.save(order);`

You can get the handle of owner order from address model by `addressModel.getOwner()` if Order is owner of the address. Else you may choose to load it from database by using `flexibleSearch.getModelByExample` or firing up a custom flexible query.

hope it helps!

Note : Hybris saves Order into Addeess as Owner during order creation. Hence order can be fetched from calling orderModel.getOwner() on delivery or payment address of an order.